# Efficient non-repeating password generator in Java

Tags: java, random, passwords, generator, non-repetitive

I have gone to this site many times and found answers to my questions but its finally time for me to post one of my own!  So the objective of a particular class in my software is to generate random passwords of fixed length, comprised of 'low' ASCII characters.  The main catch is that I do not want to generate the same password twice but always guarantee uniqueness.  Initially I used a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) in order to hash each password I had generated so far and use as a check each time I created a new one before returning.  However, Java HashMap objects are limited in size and eventually the Map would become too saturated to maintain acceptable retrieval time.  The following is my latest crack at the problem:

```
package gen;

import java.util.Set;

import java.util.Random;

import java.util.HashSet;

public class Generator {

Random r;
int length;
Set<String> seen;

public Generator(int l){
    seen = new HashSet<String>();
    length = l;
    r = new Random();
    r.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public String generate(){   
    String retval = "";
    int i = 0;
    while(i<length){
        int rand = r.nextInt(93)+33;
        if(rand!=96){
            retval+= (char)rand;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

public String generateNoRepeat(){
    String retval;
    int i;
    do{
        retval ="";
        i = 0;
        while(i<length){
            int rand = r.nextInt(93)+33;
            if(rand!=96){
                retval+= (char)rand;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }while(!seen.add(retval));
    return retval;
}
}
```

Edit: Thanks so much for the Set suggestion. It makes my code so much cleaner now too!

I may decide to just use the dumb generator method to fill up a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and just multithread it to death...

Further clarification:  This is not meant to generate secure passwords.  It must simply guarantee that it will eventually generate all possible passwords and only once for a given length and character set.

Note:

I have taken everyone's insight and have come to the conclusion that sequentially generating the possible passwords and storing them to the disk is probably my best option.  Either that or simply allow duplicate passwords and supplement the inefficiency with multiple Generator threads.

Comment: Did you know that this kind of desire to avoid repeating things was the weakness in the [Nazi Enigma cryptosystem that helped enable the Allies to win World War II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine)?

Comment: Why would it be so important to avoid generating the same password twice? As long as the probability of duplicates was sufficiently low (and unpredictable) there's no real compromise of security.

Comment: Is there any reason for using a Boolean in your `Map` if it's always true? You can try using a `Set` instead

Comment: Hm, I think your right, the [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29) seems to fit the bill, but is it bounded...

Comment: If you are generating passwords, then you might want to be using SecureRandom

Comment: I know this seems like a typical security issue, but its really for the purpose of testing not actual users.  Although your comments are helping me think of issues I should address.

Comment: "This is not meant to generate secure passwords. It must simply guarantee that it will eventually generate all possible passwords and only once for a given length and character set."  -- then iterate through them in a standard way e.g. 'aaaaaaaa' - 'zzzzzzzz'.

Comment: Yes, that is the straight forward approach, but I want to randomly explore the search space.  Correct me if I'm wrong but won't that produce a greater probability of producing a single particular character combination rather than iterating through combinations until I hit that particular character combination?

Comment: The thought had occurred to me to generate all possible combinations, store them, then index them and remove passwords as I 'use' them (like a rainbow hash?), but the amount of storage space needed to hold that many entries is too large for standard Java hashed collections...

Comment: You need to keep in mind that if you are "stateful" as you are generating passwords (that is you keep track of the ones you have generated) you need to persist this somewhere so you can stop/restart without losing progress.  That's a signficant problem if you have a large number of combinations you are trying to keep track of.  emory's answer doesn't suffer from the stateful problem in the same way - at most you need to store the number you are up to.

Comment: Thanks for the thought provoking comment.  It has lead me to discover [MegaMap](http://megamap.sourceforge.net/documentation.html).  I'm about to give it a try!

Comment: Why the focus on efficiency?  Password generation is a rare event, are you expecting to be generating 1000s of user accounts per second?  And don't forget if you are going to store this to disk then you should encrypt it so that if someone gains access to your storage, they don't get a a list of all your users passwords in plain text.  In summary, just generate a random password and don't worry about uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just encrypt sequential numbers?

Let n be the first number in your sequence (don't start with zero).  Let e be some encryption algorithm (e.g. RSA).

Then your passwords are e(n), e(n+1), e(n+2), ...

But I heavily agree with Greg Hewgill and Ted Hopp, avoiding duplicates is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of exploitative searching algorithms (like dictionary attacks)?  That's kind of what I'm going for, but I want the generation probability of each password to still be as close to equal as possible.  You make a good point though.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that generating all possible passwords and storing them on disk is the way to go.  This way, all I need to do is track how many I have left and remove the index I decide to 'use' each time.